# Why is this PH3 considered to be an unhybridized molecule?

Tags: hybridization

Also, don't hybrid orbitals appear in all molecules?

[image]

The answer by "ron" says "the molecule can be viewed as being unhybridized":
[How does lone pair of a central atom affect the dipole moment?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/how-does-lone-pair-of-a-central-atom-affect-the-dipole-moment)

Comment: It is considered unhybridized because of its geometry. Also, hybridized orbitals are a mathematical abstraction, so the words "appear", "observe", or even "exist" do not apply to them.

Comment: Read: [Hybridization in PH3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14791/4945)  (maybe dupelicate) Related: [Why is the bond angle H-P-H smaller than H-N-H?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14087/4945) In general: [Bond angles for the hydrides](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33818/4945)

Answer (score -1):

I'll try to explain this by comparing this with the case of NH3. 
N is a better electron withdrawing group than P. So in the case of NH3 the electron cloud is more closer to N. And therefore the repulsion in the bonds causes the 3 H atoms to be farther away from each other resulting in a bond angle of about 109°. But in the case of PH3 the electron cloud is farther away from the central atom(P) than in the case of NH3. So the bond pair - bond pair repulsion is comparatively lesser, causing the 3 H atoms to move closer together to an angle of almost 90°, resembling the px, py, and pz orbitals, as a consequence it's lone pairs are present in almost pure s - orbital. So it is is said that PH3 can be viewed as unhybridized.

Answer (score -3):

It is due to greater difference in energy of atomic orbitals of phosphorous such as 3s and 3p.